# A rock on a beach

Tags: greek, myth-identification

I've heard of a story in greek mythology, but I am missing a lot of details. Can you help me recover the place where, supposedly, everything happened ?

A guy goes alone to a village to steal wine and gold. When the villagers find out, they chase him. He decides to flee by the sea, with a boat. And when the villagers get to the beach, someone giant arrives, and throws a rock on the villagers. The rock has stayed here since then.

This should have happened on the West coast of Greece.

Comment: Someone giant as in tall or a giant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, the story had been completely deformed by the person who told it to me. It was supposed to be the story of Ulysses and Polyphemus the cyclops.